# convert zip file template to xml for blogger

Tags: xml, templates, zip, blogger

Bottom Line:  I'm trying to upload a template in Blogger.

The template I purchased is in zip format.  Blogger requires the template to be in XML format. I was able to unzip the file, however it unzipped in multiple folders and I do not know how to convert this to XML. This is where I am stuck.
I'm using a Chromebook. I only have access to cloud tools and chrome extensions.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Cant Understand what you mean by unzip in multiple folder. You have access to cloud tools just upload it on a cloud storage then unzip from other PC regularly. Among those multiple folders the xml must be in one of them.